# how can check the existence of record in multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can i check the existence of `bomItem` field value in three different table before inserting the record to the table. I want to check whether

```
    1. `bomitem` of `BOMHEAD` Table with `itemId` of `Table A`
         or
    2. `bomitem` of `BOMHEAD` Table with `itemId` of `Table B`
         or 
    3. `bomitem` of `BOMHEAD` Table with `itemId` of `Table C`
```

are equal

If exist in either of the three table its good to create a record in `BOMHEAD` table. The only common field in the above three table is `itemId` field they contains widely different attributes.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD](
    [bomItem] [int] NOT NULL,
    [bomRev] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Sample Data**

```
Table A
100199
100200
100201

Table B.
200199
200200
200201
200202

table C
400199
400200
400201
```

Now i want to add i want to record to `BOMHEAD`

```
INSERT INTO BOMHEAD (bomItem) VALUES (400199); //OK since exist in Table C
INSERT INTO BOMHEAD (bomItem) VALUES (200202); //OK since exist in Table B
INSERT INTO BOMHEAD (bomItem) VALUES (500202); //NO because doesnt exist in either A or B or C tables
```

Comment: What is the source ? From which table you pull the records and insert into `BOMHEAD`.

Comment: Table A or B or C.  Inorder to insert record into `BOMHEAD` table there must be  matching record  either in  Table A or Table B or Table C (just bomItem field relative) .

Comment: What should happen when all the three tables are having `bomitem`

Comment: ItemId field is in the three tables A,B, C are  auto-counter field like Table A starts from 100199 --- table B 200199--- and table C 400199 for now.

Comment: Can you sample data and expected result

Comment: Have you looked at any "check before insert" questions on SO and pondered how to extend them to checking three tables? What other work have you done?

Comment: i tried use foreign key constraints for each table but that doesn't work i get https://i.stack.imgur.com/unVLE.png i also use select Case but that i am having big time getting it work

Comment: @Prdp Added sample Data and expected output at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` to check the existence of records in the tables. Here is one way

```
INSERT INTO BOMHEAD(bomItem)
SELECT bomItem
FROM   (VALUES (400199),
               (200202),
               (200202))tc(bomItem) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA A WHERE tc.bomItem = A.itemId)
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB B WHERE tc.bomItem = B.itemId)
        OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableC C WHERE tc.bomItem = C.itemId)
```

Another approach(may not be as efficient as above query. Run it with your real data to check the performance).

```
INSERT INTO BOMHEAD
            (bomItem)
SELECT bomItem
FROM   (VALUES (400199),
               (200202),
               (200202))tc(bomItem)
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   (SELECT itemId FROM TableA A
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT itemId FROM TableB B
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT itemId FROM TableC C) a
               WHERE  a.itemId = tc.bomItem)
```

Comment: Thankyou! how can i add it as a constrain or  with create table statement rather using specific records?.

Comment: @afri - You cannot handle this as a constraint. Either you need a trigger or  while inserting make sure you do the above check.

Comment: Thank you so much. if you can give some hint on how to convert this as a trigger will be great.

Comment: @afri - Look up for `Instead of` trigger in `Sql Server`. Inside the trigger use my code for insert into `BOMHEAD` table. In my code replace the `table valued constructor(values)` with `Inserted` special table to compare the inserted records.

Comment: @afri - If you are struck somewhere then ask a new question with whatever you have tried. We are here to help you

Comment: Perfect,Thanks so much!!